# Is there a way to create RDBMS-behavior in Excel for row column lookups?

Tags: excel, lookup, vlookup

Is it possible to lookup values in excel in the following method:

### Table 1

```
ID    |     Code
-----------------
1     |      I
1     |      J
1     |      K
2     |      I
2     |      J
2     |      L
```

### Table 2

```
ID    |    I      |    J    |    K    |    L    
----------------------------------------------
1     |   14.40   |  12.33  |  9.21   |  
2     |   13.99   |  11.28  |         |   32.33
```

The lookup would be to add the column values in table 2 next to the table 'code' in table 1. So table 1 would change to:

### Table 1

```
ID    |  Code  |  Amount
-------------------------
1     |   I    |   14.40
1     |   J    |   12.33
1     |   K    |   9.21 
1     |   L    |   
2     |   I    |   13.99
2     |   J    |   11.28
2     |   K    |   
2     |   L    |   32.33
```

As a reminder, this is a project being run in Microsoft Excel 2003.

### Update

I believe I can use a vlookup on the first column and given I *know* the placement of the code fields, I could go this route but the issue would be I cannot copy and paste this formula across an entire column because the order of which codes may appear can vary (and are not the same from ID to ID).

Comment: You may wish to read http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Index and Match

```
=INDEX($C$4:$E$6,MATCH(H3,$B$4:$B$6,0),MATCH(I3,$C$3:$E$3,0))
```

Match finds the position of your ID and code in the Table 2 row and column headers. Index uses those to return the intersection of the row & column.

Comment: thank you for your response. I'd like to test it out. What columns/rows are you assuming data sits in?

Comment: In my example Table 2 is B3:E6, so column headers are C3:E3, row headers B4:B6, and data values are C4:E6. H3 and I3 are the ID and Code being looked up.

Comment: perhaps I am missing something but your table alignment does not make sense. Table 2 is at most 3 rows with the columns headers included so it could only be b3:e6; additionally, Id and 4 codes would not fit here either. It would be a minimum of B:F. Your answer seems to imply you already transposed several elements of the table which cannot be done. I am looking to perform such a lookup on thousands of rows and hundreds of columns.

Comment: My table was just a minimal example: I assumed you would adapt to fit your requirements. If you want to email me i'll send you my workbook.

Comment: OK here's a larger example.  Google doc, but works the same way: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AiAO4V0ytrHYdDVHY0lOZnRGS2o1ZW1RWTZ6OGg3Smc&hl=en_US

Answer (score 0):

Assuming table 1 is in cells A1:B7 and table 2 is in A10:E12, you can put this formula in c2 and copy it down to c7. It's an array formula, so you need to press ctrl-shift-enter after you enter it.

```
=SUM(IF($A$11:$A$12=A2,IF($B$10:$E$10=B2,$B$11:$E$12,0)))
```

Comment: Since the ID field happens to be sequential whole numbers, you could use hlookup and base the row number on the ID field.   

   =HLOOKUP(B2,$B$10:$E$12,A2+1,FALSE)

Comment: I'll test it out. The ID's given are just samples, the real ID's are non-sequential and quite long.

Comment: I believe this is works and is correct. I'm not entirely sure how the SUM() plays into the formula though. Would you care to explain?

Comment: Great. By the way, this will only work if the values in table 2 are all numbers. If that's not always the case, use Tim Williams's index(match,match) solution.

Comment: @eggplan_parm, good comment to know. Some of our ID's do in fact contain letters as well and I was curious where the error was sitting. I'm waiting to find out where the data sits in his example to test but appreciate your candid response!

Comment: It's okay if the id is non-numeric. It's only a problem if the values in the table (not the row and column headers) aren't numbers. Remember to hit ctrl-shift-enter, not just enter.

It looks like he has table 1 in H2:I8 and table 2 in B3:F5 and the "E"s should be "F"s in the formula.

With my setup, the formula in c2 would be =INDEX($B$11:$E$12,MATCH(A2,$A$11:$A$12,0),MATCH(B2,$B$10:$E$10,0))